# Is there a software that allows to convert a jpeg graph into dataset?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphs

I have a very old graph as a .jpeg picture that I would like to convert into a dataset to be able to operate with it using R/python.
I have no idea if it is even possible. [image: old_graph]

Comment: How would that even be possible? How many datapoints are actually there? In theory, you could extract an infinite number, but the original data only had values for a small subset of all possible points on that line. Given that there are no visible points in your graph and that the quality is extremely bad, any extrapolated dataset would be a wild guess at best.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like **Graph Grabber** can do the job.

https://www.quintessa.org/software/downloads-and-demos/graph-grabber-2.0.2#download